# Exclude views from scroll view touch delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

How do you exclude specific views from having a touch delay in a `UIScrollView` when `delaysContentTouches` property is set to `YES`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me. Subclass UIScrollView, and implement only this method:

```
 - (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
    {
        NSLog(@"touchesShouldCancelInContentView");

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            return NO;
        else
            return YES;
    }
```

Comment: So that method gets called after a view is touched and the touch moves.  I want to exclude a view from the scroll view's touch delay so if you touch the view it will respond immediately.